# SunSPOT programming - cannot deploy simple SunSPOT application in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I came back after a couple of years break from SunSPOT programming.

I cannot deploy even simple SunSPOT application, following error appears:

```
No to.jar.file specified.
Using "suite\SunSpotApplication_1.0.0.jar"
Using "suite\SunSpotApplication_1.0.0.jar"
Please wait while connected Sun SPOTs are examined...
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Access denied
at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1006)
atcom.sun.spot.spotselector.CommandLineSpotSelector.writeOutput(CommandLineSpotSelector.java:113)
at com.sun.spot.spotselector.CommandLineSpotSelector.main(CommandLineSpotSelector.java:106)
Java Result: 1
C:\Program Files\Sun\SunSPOT\sdk\ant\find-spots.xml:367: Spotselector failed or was cancelled
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

I'm using

```
NetBEANS 8.0
Windows 7 64bit
SunSPOT sdk v6.0 yellow
```

Comment: And you're sure that you have permission to write to the directory that it wants to write to?